# How many elements go in a sequence if the schema doesn't specify?

Tags: soap, wsdl, schema

I've got a WSDL that I'm trying to implement.  The WSDL-reading tool I have had a bug in it that got corrected in the latest release, so I've re-imported it and re-run the codegen, and I've got a bit of a problem.

The schema contains a certain type with a sequence declaration that looks like this:

```
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="ns2:Item"/>
  </xs:sequence>
```

The original version converted that as a single `Item`.  This version converts it as an array of `Item`.  There are some other types containing sequences, and they all say stuff like

```
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" ref="ns2:SomeType"/>
```

Those get unambiguously interpreted as arrays.  But when it doesn't give bounds like that, what's the correct interpretation?  Is it an array or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default for `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` is 1.

Comment: So that makes it a single object?  Why declare it as a sequence then?  (Sorry, I'm a bit of a n00b when it comes to SOAP and WSDLs.)

Comment: `sequence` has nothing to do with multiplicity. `sequence` means that the contents must appear in the specified order, as opposed to `choice` which means there must be one of the enclosed contents, or `all` which means that the contents can occur in any order.